# How can I make a completed tetris row flash before its removed?

Tags: javascript

So I'm making a Tetris game and so far It's pretty much complete except for I'm not able to track a current score or highs score. And If you complete a row that row will be removed. However, I want to add a nice effect to the row before it gets removed. I want all completed rows to flash black and white for 1s. I've tried to set an interval that would use a for loop to change all the colors in the row. But it doesn't work because the game engine is running in an interval so it's called before the other interval can finish. Any Ideas?

```js
const J = [[[1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],

           [[0, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]], 

           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 1]],

           [[0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 1]]]

const L = [[[0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],

           [[0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1]], 

           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 0]], 
            
           [[1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]]]

const O = [[[1, 1],
            [1, 1]],
        
           [[1, 1],
            [1, 1]],
            
           [[1, 1],
            [1, 1]],

           [[1, 1],
            [1, 1]]]

                       

const I = [[[0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]],

           [[0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0]],
        
           [[0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1]],
        
           [[0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0]]]

const S = [[[0, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0]],
            
           [[0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 1]],
        
           [[0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0]],
            
           [[1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]]] 
           
const T = [[[0, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],
            
           [[0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0]],

           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0]],

           [[0, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]]] 
           
const Z = [[[1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],
           
           [[0, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0]],
        
           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1]],
           
           [[0, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [1, 0, 0]]]
            

const col = 10;
const row = 20;
const vacant = "black";
const cvs = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
const sq = 35;
//collect blocks from blocks.js and assign a color
const blocks = [[J, 'blue'], 
                [L, 'orange'], 
                [O, 'yellow'], 
                [I, 'cyan'], 
                [S, 'limegreen'], 
                [T, 'purple'], 
                [Z, 'red']]

let board = [];
for(let r = 0; r < row; r++) {
    board[r] = [];
    for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
        board[r][c] = vacant;
        draw(c, r, board[r][c]);
    }
}

//create a blueprint function to draw to the board
function draw(x, y, color) {
    //set the drawing specifications
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x * sq, y * sq, sq, sq);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white"; //?????change to color
    ctx.strokeRect(x * sq, y * sq, sq, sq);
}

function drawBlock(blockPosition, color) {
    for(let r = 0; r < blockPosition.length; r++) {
        for(let c = 0; c < blockPosition[r].length; c++) {
            if(blockPosition[r][c] == 0) continue;
            draw(block.x + c, block.y + r, color);
        }
    }
}
   
class Block {
    constructor(block, color) {
        this.blockSet = block;
        this.color = color;
        this.index = 0;
        this.blockPosition = block[this.index];
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = -1;
    }

    moveLeft() {
        if(!block.hascollided(-1, 0, this.blockPosition)) {
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, vacant);
            this.x--;
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, this.color);
        }
    }

    moveRight() {
        if(!block.hascollided(1, 0, this.blockPosition)) {
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, vacant);
            this.x++;
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, this.color);
        }
    }

    moveDown() {
        if(!block.hascollided(0, 1, this.blockPosition)) {
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, vacant);
            this.y++;
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, this.color);
        } else {
            for(let r = 0; r < this.blockPosition.length; r++) {
                for(let c = 0; c < this.blockPosition.length; c++) {
                    if(this.blockPosition[r][c] == 0) continue;
                    if(this.y + r <= 0) {
                        alert("Game Over!");
                        
                    }
                    board[this.y + r][this.x + c] = this.color;
                    checkForPoints();
                    block = newBlock();
                }
            }        
        }
    }

    rotate() {
        let nextPosition = this.blockSet[(this.index + 1) % 4];

        let kick = 0;

        if(block.hascollided(0, 0, nextPosition)) {
            if(block.x < col/2) {
                if(this.x == -2) kick = 2;
                else kick = 1;

            }
            if(block.x > col/2) {
                if(this.color == "cyan") kick = -2;
                else kick = -1;

            }
        }

        if(!block.hascollided(kick, 0, nextPosition))
        drawBlock(this.blockPosition, vacant);
        this.index = (this.index + 1) % 4;
        this.blockPosition = this.blockSet[this.index];
        this.x += kick;
        drawBlock(this.blockPosition, this.color);
    }

    hascollided(x, y, block) {
        for(let r = 0; r < block.length; r++) {
            for(let c = 0; c < block.length; c++) {
                if(block[r][c] == 0) continue;

                let newX = this.x + c + x;
                let newY = this.y + r + y;
                
                if(newX < 0 || newX >= col || newY >= row) return true;
                if(board[newY][newX] != vacant) return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

function newBlock() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * blocks.length);
    return new Block(blocks[r][0], blocks[r][1]);
}

function checkForPoints() {
    let newRows = [];

    for(let r = 0; r < board.length; r++) {
        if(board[r].every(squareCheck)) {
            for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                newRows.unshift(vacant);
            }
            
            board.splice(r, 1);
            board.unshift(newRows);
            redraw();
        }
    }

    function squareCheck(sq) {
        if(sq !== vacant) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    function redraw() {
        for(let r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                draw(c, r, board[r][c]);
            }
        }
    }
}

block = newBlock();

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{
    if(e.key == "ArrowLeft") block.moveLeft();
    else if(e.key == "ArrowUp") block.rotate();
    else if(e.key == "ArrowRight") block.moveRight();
    else if(e.key == "ArrowDown") block.moveDown();
})


let dropStart = Date.now();

function drop() {
    let now = Date.now();
    let delta = now - dropStart;

    if(delta > 800) {
        dropStart = Date.now();
        block.moveDown();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(drop);
}

drop();
```

```css
body, html {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: darkgrey;
}



canvas {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Tetris</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="700"></canvas>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't believe it. I literally play game on stackoverflow 

Answer (score 0):

You just need to manage your row removal process into 2 steps, after detecting that the row has matched, set the value in the cells so that they are in the *highlight* state, then only remove the row when it was already in the *highlight* state.

The obvious injection point is your `checkForRowMath()` function, but the timing bit is a bit trickier. Using your pattern of *time delta* for determining when to re-evaluate the state of the board, we can do the same thing to trigger the highlighted row to be removed as a separated async-logic process to the rest of the game logic.

> A few pointers, in the absence of documentation or comments, it helps if you name your functions based on the output, not necessarily the process. Specifically `squareCheck`, if this is renamed to `notVacant` then the output or result of the function is easier to interpret, but also you can identify points in the logic where we might want to detect other states, in this case the first thing i thought of was `isHighlight`. The same goes for `checkForPoints()` this name doesn't really describe the outcome, it describes the process that it uses, when really this could be named something like `checkForRowMatch()`

So sticking with your current style, do the following:

1. Define a new constant `highlight = "white"`
2. Define a new global variable `hlStart` that will record the start of the highlight state
3. In `checkForPoints` break the collision handling into two steps, first set the cells to `highlight` and set the time into `hlStart`

   - then on the next pass, if all the cells are *high lighted*, only *then* do you remove them
4. In `drop` (the main game loop) add some logic to call `checkForPoints()` after a delay to manage the 2nd step in the collision logic.

Drop now looks something like this:

```
let dropStart = Date.now();
let hlStart = null;

function drop() {
    let now = Date.now();
    let delta = now - dropStart;

    if(delta > 800) {
        dropStart = Date.now();
        block.moveDown();
    }
    
    if(hlStart) {
        let hlDelta = Date.now() - hlStart;
        if (hlDelta > 600) {
            hlStart = null;
            checkForPoints();
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(drop);
}
```

And `checkForPoints()` has been changed to separately highlight and then later remove the matched row:

> In this snip it is possible for multiple rows to be matched at the same time, but the user would never see the result of repainting the board between individual row matches that are detected, so we set a flag to indicate that *any* change on the board requires a re-draw, then only call `redraw` once.

```
function checkForPoints() {
    let newRows = [];
    let changed = false;

    for(let r = 0; r < board.length; r++) {
        // if the row has already been highlighted
        // then this time we can remove it
        if(board[r].every(isHighlight)) {
            for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                newRows.unshift(vacant);
            }
            
            board.splice(r, 1);
            board.unshift(newRows);
      
            changed = true;
        }
        // Only check for notVacant if the row is not highlighted.
        else if(board[r].every(notVacant)) {
            for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                board[r][c] = highlight;
            }
            // record the start time for the highlight animation
            hlStart = Date.now();
            changed = true;
        } 
    }

    // because multiple rows could be affected at the same time, moved
    // redraw out to a single call for each whole board pass
    if (changed)
        redraw();

    function notVacant(sq) {
        if(sq !== vacant) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    function isHighlight(sq) {
        if(sq === highlight) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    function redraw() {
        for(let r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                draw(c, r, board[r][c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Putting this together we get the following solution:

```js
const J = [[[1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],

           [[0, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]], 

           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 1]],

           [[0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 1]]]

const L = [[[0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],

           [[0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1]], 

           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 0]], 
            
           [[1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]]]

const O = [[[1, 1],
            [1, 1]],
        
           [[1, 1],
            [1, 1]],
            
           [[1, 1],
            [1, 1]],

           [[1, 1],
            [1, 1]]]

                       

const I = [[[0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]],

           [[0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0]],
        
           [[0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1]],
        
           [[0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0]]]

const S = [[[0, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0]],
            
           [[0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 1]],
        
           [[0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0]],
            
           [[1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]]] 
           
const T = [[[0, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],
            
           [[0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0]],

           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0]],

           [[0, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 0]]] 
           
const Z = [[[1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0]],
           
           [[0, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 0]],
        
           [[0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1]],
           
           [[0, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [1, 0, 0]]]
            

const col = 10;
const row = 20;
const vacant = "black";
// 1. define the highlight color / state
const highlight = "white";
const cvs = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
const sq = 35;
//collect blocks from blocks.js and assign a color
const blocks = [[J, 'blue'], 
                [L, 'orange'], 
                [O, 'yellow'], 
                [I, 'cyan'], 
                [S, 'limegreen'], 
                [T, 'purple'], 
                [Z, 'red']]

let board = [];
for(let r = 0; r < row; r++) {
    board[r] = [];
    for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
        board[r][c] = vacant;
        draw(c, r, board[r][c]);
    }
}

//create a blueprint function to draw to the board
function draw(x, y, color) {
    //set the drawing specifications
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x * sq, y * sq, sq, sq);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white"; //?????change to color
    ctx.strokeRect(x * sq, y * sq, sq, sq);
}

function drawBlock(blockPosition, color) {
    for(let r = 0; r < blockPosition.length; r++) {
        for(let c = 0; c < blockPosition[r].length; c++) {
            if(blockPosition[r][c] == 0) continue;
            draw(block.x + c, block.y + r, color);
        }
    }
}
   
class Block {
    constructor(block, color) {
        this.blockSet = block;
        this.color = color;
        this.index = 0;
        this.blockPosition = block[this.index];
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = -1;
    }

    moveLeft() {
        if(!block.hascollided(-1, 0, this.blockPosition)) {
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, vacant);
            this.x--;
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, this.color);
        }
    }

    moveRight() {
        if(!block.hascollided(1, 0, this.blockPosition)) {
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, vacant);
            this.x++;
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, this.color);
        }
    }

    moveDown() {
        if(!block.hascollided(0, 1, this.blockPosition)) {
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, vacant);
            this.y++;
            drawBlock(this.blockPosition, this.color);
        } else {
            for(let r = 0; r < this.blockPosition.length; r++) {
                for(let c = 0; c < this.blockPosition.length; c++) {
                    if(this.blockPosition[r][c] == 0) continue;
                    if(this.y + r <= 0) {
                        alert("Game Over!");
                        
                    }
                    board[this.y + r][this.x + c] = this.color;
                    checkForPoints();
                    block = newBlock();
                }
            }        
        }
    }

    rotate() {
        let nextPosition = this.blockSet[(this.index + 1) % 4];

        let kick = 0;

        if(block.hascollided(0, 0, nextPosition)) {
            if(block.x < col/2) {
                if(this.x == -2) kick = 2;
                else kick = 1;

            }
            if(block.x > col/2) {
                if(this.color == "cyan") kick = -2;
                else kick = -1;

            }
        }

        if(!block.hascollided(kick, 0, nextPosition))
        drawBlock(this.blockPosition, vacant);
        this.index = (this.index + 1) % 4;
        this.blockPosition = this.blockSet[this.index];
        this.x += kick;
        drawBlock(this.blockPosition, this.color);
    }

    hascollided(x, y, block) {
        for(let r = 0; r < block.length; r++) {
            for(let c = 0; c < block.length; c++) {
                if(block[r][c] == 0) continue;

                let newX = this.x + c + x;
                let newY = this.y + r + y;
                
                if(newX < 0 || newX >= col || newY >= row) return true;
                if(board[newY][newX] != vacant) return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

function newBlock() {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * blocks.length);
    return new Block(blocks[r][0], blocks[r][1]);
}

function checkForPoints() {
    let newRows = [];
    let changed = false;

    for(let r = 0; r < board.length; r++) {
        // if the row has already been highlighted
        // then this time we can remove it
        if(board[r].every(isHighlight)) {
            for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                newRows.unshift(vacant);
            }

            board.splice(r, 1);
            board.unshift(newRows);

            changed = true;
        }
        // Only check for notVacant if the row is not highlighted.
        else if(board[r].every(notVacant)) {
            for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                board[r][c] = highlight;
            }
            // record the start time for the highlight animation
            hlStart = Date.now();
            changed = true;
        } 
    }

    // because multiple rows could be affected at the same time, moved
    // redraw out to a single call for each whole board pass
    if (changed)
        redraw();

    function notVacant(sq) {
        if(sq !== vacant) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    function isHighlight(sq) {
        if(sq === highlight) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    function redraw() {
        for(let r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                draw(c, r, board[r][c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
block = newBlock();

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{
    if(e.key == "ArrowLeft") block.moveLeft();
    else if(e.key == "ArrowUp") block.rotate();
    else if(e.key == "ArrowRight") block.moveRight();
    else if(e.key == "ArrowDown") block.moveDown();
})


let dropStart = Date.now();
let hlStart = null;

function drop() {
    let now = Date.now();
    let delta = now - dropStart;

    if(delta > 800) {
        dropStart = Date.now();
        block.moveDown();
    }


    if(hlStart) {
        let hlDelta = Date.now() - hlStart;
        if (hlDelta > 600) {
            hlStart = null;
            checkForPoints();
        }
    }
 
    requestAnimationFrame(drop);
}

drop();
```

```css
body, html {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: darkgrey;
}



canvas {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Tetris</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="700"></canvas>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly on topic for SO, but it was heaps of fun :) Matching multiple rows still needs some work, but it leaves one row highlighted. I hope it helps you on your way!

Comment: This is a cool feature! I have to try implement it into my game. @randy you can check my code if you need help with the high scores: https://github.com/melcor76/js-tetris